# In Java, how can I test if an Array contains the same value?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm looking for a method to detect if all objects within an array(list) are the same.
e. g:

```
arraylist1 = {"1", "1", "1", "1"} // elements are the same
arraylist2 = {"1", "1", "0", "1"} // elements are not the same
```

Thanks for help

Comment: is the order relevant?

Comment: no. it could also {"0", "0", "1", "0"}

Comment: @Stefan he wants all elements the same. so  {1,1,1,1} is the same as {1,1,1,1} (notice the differences in order)

Comment: Your code is setting a list to a boolean value. Is one of your `=` supposed to be `==`? Are you trying to determine whether all of the values in a list are the same value? Or are you trying to compare two lists to determine whether the two lists contain the same values, and if so, is order important?

Comment: @shoover, I think the `= true` and `= false` are just supposed to be comments indicating the output of passing that array to the method he's asking for...

Comment: @jonhopkins Thanks, I had to read it a few times to figure out what he's asking for. Now that I understand that, is he asking whether they are all "equals" or all "the same object"?

Comment: I changed it to a comment @shoover

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public static boolean AreAllSame(String[] array)
{
    boolean isFirstElementNull = array[0] == null;
    for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if(isFirstElementNull)
            if(array[i] != null) return false;
        else 
            if(!array[0].equals(array[i])) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Please feel free to correct any syntax mistakes. I fear my Java-fu may be lacking today.

Comment: @DavidWallace - I'm half tempted to see how complicated a solution I could come up with for this.

Comment: Well, yeah, it does seem to be reinventing a wheel, when all the comparison logic is already there in the `HashSet` constructor.

Comment: @DavidWallace - If I had a further use for the HashSet, then I'd agree. But creating a new instance of a collection just for that seems a waste of space.

Comment: Space which is immediately available for garbage collection, so no waste.

Comment: @hawk - Other than the fact that it doesn't catch all of the edge cases (because I'm not going to write everything for the OP), what's wrong with it?

Comment: @JustinNiessner - I think you SHOULD update it to catch the case where `array[0] == null`.  This would actually make it quite a bit more complex.  Suddenly, what _ought_ to be a simple check ends up being enough code to slow you down as you read it.

Comment: Thanks.  Appreciated.  But NOW it crashes if the array is empty.  It didn't before.

Comment: Ok. So, does Java have any decent implementation of Predicates? They would certainly help clean things up a bit.

Comment: Yeah, there's something like Predicates in ZouZou's Java 8 solution (which currently also fails to deal with the case where there are nulls in the array).  The point is, you shouldn't try to re-invent the wheel for something so simple.  How many times did you end up editing this post?  And it's _still_ not perfect.  I think that's what @hawk meant with his/her bald comment.

Comment: Probably. And you're right. Just thought I'd get a bit of the logic across to the OP (since that seemed what they were looking for). If you want a bombproof one-liner, go for the `HashSet` (unless, of course, you improperly overrode `equals` and not `hashCode`...but that's another story).

Comment: @DavidWallace - ...and if it makes you feel better, I'm the one that gave you the upvote. Haha.

Answer (score 26):

Java 8 solution :

```
boolean match = Arrays.stream(arr).allMatch(s -> s.equals(arr[0]));
```

Same logic for lists :

```
boolean match = list.stream().allMatch(s -> s.equals(list.get(0)));
```

---

It comes quite complicated if there are only or any `null` values in the array (resulting in a `NullPointerException`). So possible workarounds are:

- Using [`Predicate.isEqual`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#isEqual-java.lang.Object-), it uses the static method [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) from the [`Objects`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) class and it will do the null check for you before calling equals on the first argument.

  `boolean match = Arrays.stream(arr).allMatch(Predicate.isEqual(arr[0]));`
  `boolean match = Arrays.stream(arr).allMatch(s -> Objects.equals(arr[0], s));`
- Using  `distinct()` and `count()` :

  `boolean match = Arrays.stream(arr).distinct().count() == 1;`

  that can be improved into `Arrays.stream(arr).distinct().limit(2).count() == 1;` as there is no need to check the all pipeline's content if you already find 2 distinct elements.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if the array has a length of 0?

Comment: Returns true for an empty array.

Comment: @jlr It returns `true`. You can add a small check before for `null` and empty arrays

Comment: @ZouZou - Can you please update it for the case where there are nulls in the array?  Just so we can see how much more complicated it would have to be to deal with that case correctly?

Comment: @DavidWallace I agree that it comes quite complicated if there are only nulls value in the array. So you can also use `distinct()` and `count()`.

Comment: Yes, the solution with `distinct()` and `count()` is better than your original solution.  It just earned you an upvote, although it would be better if you had posted it as a separate answer.

Comment: No, I didn't mean to say "if there are only null values" - I meant "if there are any null values".

Comment: very nice and clean solution.

Answer (score 6):

```
if( new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(yourArray)).size() == 1 ){
    // All the elements are the same
}
```

Comment: seems no once cares about empty array

Comment: Well, I assumed that OP already knows how to see if an array is empty.  I guess he could change `==` to `<=` if he wants `true` in the empty case.

Comment: I'm thinking this would cause two iterations over the collection where the optimal solution could do it in a single iteration (one iteration for `asList` and another for the `HashSet` constructor).

Comment: @JustinNiessner - This solution doesn't do two iterations.  `asList` doesn't iterate, it just wraps.

Comment: @DavidWallace - I'll take your word for it. I don't know enough about the Java internals.

Comment: I am not goog in java internal , but I think copying array to new hash set is reducing in performance and increasing memory consumption for arrays with million elements

Comment: @hawk Why do you think that?  It's doing `n-1` comparisons, which is the minimum number that you actually need.  I don't believe you will come up with any solution that performs better than this one.

Comment: @DavidWallace no I am not taking about comparison, new HashSet obviously will create a copy of original array, THEN it will start comparison yes n-1

Comment: No, it will not "obviously create a copy" - it iterates through the original array, comparing and inserting as it goes.

Comment: +1 for a nice one-liner solution that works for earlier versions of Java ;)

Comment: ok, any proof ? from docs hash set construct a NEW set containing elements from specified collection )

Comment: Yes, it creates a set.  It doesn't create a new array first, then organise it into a set.

Comment: @hawk - You are right.  This won't be particularly performant for large arrays.  I need to rethink this.

Answer (score 2):

If your list is empty return true.
If not, loop through it and check if all elements are equal to the element at index 0.
If so, return true, otherwise return false.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public boolean containsSameValues(int[] array) {
     if(array.length == 0) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array is empty");
     }
     int first = array[0];
     for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
         if(array[i] != first) {
             return false;
         }
      }
      return true;
 }
```

Comment: Do you mean to have `!=` in the condition?  I think `if(!array[i].equals(first))` would make more sense.  Of course, then you need a null check as well.

Comment: Not really, my method has `int` array as a parameter(which is wrong because OP has String array but maybe somebody will find it useful)

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean containsAllValues=false;
boolean t=false;
int isto=0; 
for(int k=0;k<arraylist1.size();k++){
   for(int n=0;n<arraylist2.size();n++){
       if(arraylist1.get(k).equals(arraylist2.get(n))){
           t=true;
       }
   }
   if(t){
       isto++;
   }else{
       isto=0;
       break;
   }
}
if(isto!=0){
   containsAllValues=true;
}
```

With this you can check if arraylist2 contains values from arraylist1.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the array and then use the Array equals method:

```
public boolean equalArrays(int []f ,int [] g){
        Arrays.sort(f);
        Arrays.sort(g);
        if (Arrays.equals(f, g))
             return true;
        return false;
}
```

To test it out:

```
         int [] h={1,1,0,1};
         int [] t={1,1,1,0};
         System.out.println(cc.equalArrays(h,t));
```

Answer (score 1):

For Java 8, Alexis C's solution is probably the best. However, if you're stuck with <= Java 7 and don't think David Wallace's approach is expressive enough, you could also try this:

```
boolean result = Collections.frequency(yourList, "1") == yourList.size();
```

Basically what this does is that it checks whether the number of elements in your list equal to "1" matches the total number of elements in the list. Pretty straightforward.

By the way -- this is pure Java `Collections API`, and I believe `Collection.frequency(..)` has been there since at least JDK 1.5. See the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object)) for more information.

EDIT: Here's a [quick fiddle](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMLVpFcjRSSkN0QUE) if you want to take this for a test drive.

Comment: This is for a list not an array

Answer (score 0):

The easiest one:

```
public static boolean checkTheSame(int[] numbers)  {
   for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++)  {
       if (numbers[i] != numbers[i + 1])  {
           return false;
       }
   }

   return true;
}
```