# Compare all members of a list

Tags: java

Lets say I have a list of objects. How can I compare all of the lists members in an elegant way?

My idea is to check 2 members and iterate to the next one.
If 1st equals 2nd and 2nd equals 3rd ... then all are equal by transitivity.

But I think there should be are better way.

```
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();
lst.add("a");
lst.add("b");

String last = null;
boolean ok = true;
for (String s : lst) {
    if (last != null && !last.equals(s)) {
        ok = false;
        break;
    }

    last = s; 
}
```

**EDIT**

My question is not about finding a better algorithm. I am looking for a built-in function that does it for me so I do not need to do the algorithm myself.

Comment: I want to check if all elements have a same attribute. In my sample it is the content of the string itself. I think for that and because of transitivity only n-1 checks are required.

Comment: Not related: `last.equals(s) == false` => `!last.equals(s)`

Comment: What is the goal? If you want to get rid of duplicates, why not just turn the list into a set? If the set has length 1, you know that all list elements were equal.

Comment: The [answer to this request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21170680/6538278) shows a very elegant way to do this, using properties of the `HashSet` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve what you need. This post provides different examples using the basic loops, collections API, Streams and Third-Party libraries - https://www.baeldung.com/java-list-all-equal

Since you asked for the most elegant way, here are some examples that I considered such:

**Use HashSet** - If we convert a List to a HashSet and the resulting size is less than or equal to 1, then we know that all elements in the list are equal:

```
public boolean verifyAllEqualUsingHashSet(List<String> list) {
    return new HashSet<String>(list).size() <= 1;
}
```

**Java 8+ Streams** - Count the distinct elements. If result is <= 1, then all values are equal.

```
public boolean verifyAllEqualUsingStream(List<String> list) {
    return list.stream()
      .distinct()
      .count() <= 1;
}
```

**Collections API** - frequency method returns the number of elements in a Collection c matching an Object. So, if the frequency result is equal to the size of the list, we know that all the elements are equal:

```
public boolean verifyAllEqualUsingFrequency(List<String> list) {
    return list.isEmpty() || Collections.frequency(list, list.get(0)) == list.size();
}
```

Comment: Out of all the examples shown, option 3 (basic looping) and 6.2 (allMatch) are the most efficient because if there is one unequal element in the middle of the list, it will return false immediately. The other algorithms will scan the whole list regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Compare all elements with the first element. It turns out N-1 operations, it can not be less.

Comment: Yes but thats the same that I do but I do the neighbours. But can I do it in Java with a builtin function more elegant?

Comment: You can make it more elegant (less code), but it will not be more efficient.

Comment: e.g. `boolean allEqual = new HashSet(theList).size() == 1` is no more efficient, probably less.

Comment: It can be less than N-1 operations, because if it finds an unequal element in the middle of the list, it doesn't have to check any other elements.

Comment: The difficulty is considered for the worst case!